# Regex to remove inline javascript from string

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove inline javascript for a given string. Examples:

If user typed: `<img onload="something" />`

I should need to convert into `<img />`

I created this PHP code and it works(apparently without issues):

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
function test_input($input){
  //I have a list with all events but for this example I used two
  $html_events = 'onload|onclick';
  $pattern = "/(<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[^>]*)($html_events)([\s]*=[\s]*)('[^>]*'|\"[^>]*\")([^>]*>)/i";
  $replacement = '$1$5';
  while( preg_match($pattern, $input) ){
    $input = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
  }
  return htmlentities($input);
}

echo test_input('<img onload="alert(\'hello world\');" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');" />'). '<br />';
echo test_input('<img onload="alert(\'hello world\');"/>'). '<br />';
echo test_input('<div onload="alert(\'hello world\');" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');">hello buddies</div>'). '<br />';
```

I'm just looking for improvements or use cases that I did not supporting or that break my regex. I would appreciate if you tell me:

This: `test_input('something bad');` breaks your regex.

Or if found an improvement that in a benchmark demonstrate better performance I should be happy to apply it as long as it does not break use cases already supported.

Thank You!

**Update**
I finally used [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: Dear lord, let us pray that Cthulhu doesn't get word of this. Regex _is not the tool for the job_! Parse the markup, iterate the nodes, and check the attributes. If an `onload` or `onlclick` attribute is found remove it

Comment: I've added an answer that shows you how to parse, and remove any attribute you need removing...

Answer (score 5):

Parsing markup with regex is like building your house using lego... it's not the right tool for the job. HTML is not *a regular language*, therefore *regular* expressions don't cut the mustard. More than that: [You're actively working to bring the world as we know it to an end, which drives people insane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
What you need is a DOM parser, and as luck would have it, PHP has the `DOMDocument` object, which is just that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<img onload="alert(\'hello world\');" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');" />');
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');//just get all nodes, 
//$dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); would work, too
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    if ($node->hasAttribute('onload'))
    {
        $node->removeAttribute('onload');
    }
    if ($node->hasAttribute('onclick'))
    {
        $node->removeAttribute('onclick');
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();//will include html, head, body tags and doctype
```

Tadaa... both `onload` and `onclick` have been removed from the markup, without the pain of writing a reliable and stable regex, that can deal with in-line JS... As an added bonus, this code will be far more maintainable (and expandable) in the future. I'd much prefer maintaining this code, than having to rework a regular expression somebody wrote a couple of months ago...

If you want, you can echo only the tags you've changed, like so:

```
$changed = array();
$attributesOfDeath = array('onload', 'onclick');
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $current = null;
    foreach($attributesOfDeath as $attr)
    {
        if ($node->hasAttribute($attr))
        {
            $node->removeAttribute($attr);
            $current = $node;
        }
    }
    if ($current)
    {
        $changed[] = $current;//add to changed array
    }
}
$changed = array_map(array($dom, 'saveXML'), $changed);
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $changed);
```

As Jan said, for maintainability it's best to use an array of *"forbidden attributes"*. That's what the `$attributesOfDeath` array is for. If you want to, later on, check for a third or fourth attribute, you can simply add that to the array, and nothing else in your code need change. It'll just keep on working as before.

Comment: for the purposes of maintainability, you should put `onload` and `onclick` in a single array and iterate over it. Otherwise, I agree with the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not only that, though I did think about doing that in my code example: when using this code, it might be worth while using a class (assigning the `DOMDocument` instance to a property, so as to not create a new instance on each function call). Anyway, I've edited my answer, and now use an `$attributesOfDeath` array in my second example

Answer (score 0):

#### Regex to [Strip all Inline JS](https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/top-15-commonly-used-regex/)

You can use the following Regex to Strip off Inline JS

```
/\bon\w+=\S+(?=.*>)/g
```

[Demo](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=104055)
[Reference](https://digitalfortress.tech/tricks/top-15-commonly-used-regex/)